# SSH stuck while git clone

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I ran git clone on a repository on bitbucket but ssh is stuck and wouldn't clone.

Running ps to see the command, I rexecuted it in dubug mode and here is the output.

```
>>ssh -v git@bitbucket.org git-upload-pack 'username/repo.git'
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 131.103.20.168 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
```

From there on it just hangs and does nothing.

Comment: You most likely have a firewall blocking your outgoing ssh access. Talk to your local network administrators. For someone here to help you, it'd be very helpful for you to describe the local network architecture. How are you connected to the Internet and who manages the local network?